# Getting null pointer when using Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties with Android AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, nullpointerexception, storage, appwidgetprovider

I am writing an Android widget using `AppWidgetProvider`. To store some values (f.e. downloaded JSON data) I am using `Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties`.

Unfortunately I am getting a null pointer exception (app crashes) after a while (I guess when the system is killing the application in background).

Because I can't just call `LoadApplication(new App())` from my `AppWidgetProvider` instance I am wondering what to do to prevent `Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current` from being null. Am I doing something wrong here in general? Maybe `Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties` is not meant to be used like this.

Comment: If can't use `Properties`, in android, you can use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to store your data.